# How to find the longest running queries in sybase ASE 15?

Tags: database, performance, sybase, sap-ase

How to find the longest running queries in sybase ASE 15 ?

Do we need to use MDA tables or is there another way ?

Answer (score 4):

Without using the MDA tables, you can first look at the system table `master..syslogshold`.

Otherwise you can use the MDA tables `master..monProcessStatement` and `master..monProcessSQLText`.

You can also look at `sp_monitor 'statement'`.